# global variables value changes automatically?

Tags: c

```
...

char A,M,Q,Q_1,count;

int main()

{

    system("cls");
    count=8;
    printf("%d",count);
    printf("\n\tEnter the Multiplicand(M) : ");
    scanf("%d",&M);
    printf("\n\tEnter the Multiplier(Q) : ");
    scanf("%d",&Q);
        printf("%d",count);    //prints 0???????
.......

}
```

I don't understand how the value of 'count' changes to 0.

plz help...
thanks.

System : win7/VS2008

EDIT:
After having an insight on what I was doing(thanks to Péter Török ),I moved the assignment to 'count' after scanfs,this solved the problem...thanks.

Comment: Both are important, but I (and, I think, most people) prefer horizontal whitespace (spaces, tabs) to vertical whitespace (empty lines)

Comment: Oh ... and try to stay away from global variables

Comment: yeah I don't like them either but I made it for someone newbie(relatively) in C

Comment: Simply moving the assignment to `count` doesn't solve the problem, even though it may seem to. You still have a buffer overflow/data corruption bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you attempt to read an integer (`%d`) with `scanf` and store it in a `char` variable, there is a memory overflow: a `char` is 1 byte while an `int` is (usually) 4. The result is that the memory area after the variables `M`, and then `Q`, gets overwritten. And this happens to affect `count` too.

Declare your variables as `int` to avoid this (or explicitly read `char` values with `scanf` - but if you want to multiply values, it is better to start with `int`s right away, to at least mitigate the risk of integer overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Don't lie to the compiler.

You first said M is a char

```
char A,M,...
```

and then tried to use it as an int

```
scanf("%d",&M);
```

Don't do that!

Either declare M (and the other variables) as int, or scanf a char

Comment: the program does bit operations on A,M & N & the value supplied was in the range of 255 n there is big array of these nos I removed other details so I thought I could save some run time memory usage by using a char....clearly I created a mess on my  own.

Comment: If you have a large number of values, it's best to use `char` (maybe `unsigned char` for bit operations). With C99 you can scanf a `char` value with `"%hhd"` (`"%hhu"` for `unsigned char`)